# Некорректно работает вывод чисел в файл

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть два файла `intput.txt` и `output.txt`. В первый файл мне нужно записать 2 строки: в первую длину массива, во вторую сам массив с числами не превышающими 31. А во второй файл мне нужно записать уже 3 строки: в первой строке нечетные числа массива записанного в первом файле, во второй строке четные числа и в третьей слово `YES` если четных чисел больше чем нечетных или слово `NO` если наоборот. Вот пример:

```
input.txt:

6
2 4 5 6 7 8

output.txt:

5 7
2 4 6 8
YES
```

Задачу я уже почти решил, вот мой код:

```
var input = "Input.txt";
var output = "Output.txt";
var array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ')
.Where(x => x.Length > 0).Where(x => int.Parse(x) <= 31).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllText(input, array.Length + Environment.NewLine + string.Join(" ", array));
var readFile = File.ReadAllText(input).Remove(0, 1); // здесь я удаляю число обозначающее длину
var even = readFile.Where(x => (x % 2 == 0)).ToArray();
var odd = readFile.Where(x => (x % 2 != 0)).ToArray();
File.WriteAllText(output, string.Join(" ", odd));
File.WriteAllText(output, string.Join(" ", even));
```

Моя проблема такова: во-первых в файл `output.txt` записывается только вторая строка то есть четные числа, во-вторых записываются они коряво, будто из основного массива просто удалили нечетные числа и на месте пробелов не поставили ничего. Выглядит это так:

```
 2   4     6     8
```

Ну и в третьих, программа некорректно работает с двузначными числами. Точнее не вся программа, а только когда дело уже доходит до файла `output.txt`. Когда я ввожу двузначные числа, например, `10 22 23 26`, то в файл `input.txt` все записывается правильно, а именно:

```
4
10 22 23 26
```

Но когда дело доходит до второго файла, то программа не воспринимает двузначные числа, она считает что, к примеру, число `22` это два разных числа и поэтому на выходе получается что-то вроде этого:

```
 0   2 2   2   2 6
```

Как вы видите, число 10 она вообще не выводит так как считает что это `1` и `0`

Прошу помочь мне с этой проблемой. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста давайте своим вопросам более конкретные заголовки. Обычно заголовок о том, что делает или что должен делать код. Несмотря на то что для текущего вопроса заголовок сформулировать не так просто, я все же попытался, и теперь он в себе несет немного больше информации, чем никакой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var readFile = File.ReadAllText(input).Remove(0, 1);
```

Что возвращает `ReadAllText`? Вы думаете, что список. А на самом деле - строку, из которой Вы удаляете один символ.

---

```
var even = readFile.Where(x => (x % 2 == 0)).ToArray();
```

Что здесь `x`? Вы думаете, что число.  А на самом деле - символ.

---

```
File.WriteAllText(output, string.Join(" ", even));
```

Что делает `WriteAllText`? Вы думаете, что добавляет текст в файл. А на самом деле - полностью пeреписывает файл новым содержимым.

---

Гугл Вас еще не заблокировал, вся документация доступна.